# Why are my standard formulas opening as array formulas on other systems?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, compatibility

I'm developing an input template in Excel for a client and recently they've been sending it back saying it's full of #VALUE! errors. After a bit of toing and froing we found that formulas that look like this at my end:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("D" &ROW() & ":AT" &ROW()))<>$BA$1,INDIRECT("E" &ROW())=""),"name not entered","")
```

Were opening like this at theirs:

```
{=IF(AND(COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("D" &ROW() & ":AT" &ROW()))<>$BA$1,INDIRECT("E" &ROW())=""),"name not entered","")}
```

I've tried googling a fix for this, but the results always just return *how* to use array formulas. This could be down to me not knowing what search terms to use.

I have gathered that the @ sign *could* be used, but haven't been able to properly figure out how to use this.

As a side note, I'm using the `Indirect(CollLetter & Row())` formulas to reference very specific cells, as there were a lot of users who were cutting and pasting within the data entry portion of the template at breaking the existing formulas.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

A copy with the commercially sensitive information stripped out is hosted here:
[Forced Array formula, example](http://www.filedropper.com/nstarrayissuecopy)

The formulas causing the problem start in column AD and continue right to column BR. When this file was saved, all these formulas appear as standard formula, but when my client opens the document they are converted to Array formulas, with a #VALUE! result.

I can't recreate the issue on my own computer, so this may open fine for others as well.

Comment: This is an unusual behavior,,  Excel or even Computer  never acts like unless not been commanded for it. Please [edit] you post & share the WB on cloud to examine the issue to fix.

Comment: Hi Rajesh,
I've included a link to the cleaned copy of the workbook to my question.

Comment: Hi @Andy,, I've downloaded the file ,, give me some time to check it.

Comment: Hi @Andy,, now [check this](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2jfzbdskht18afkqkh1c7/NstArrayIssueCopy.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=jcw1mcq049v7b4m2l5ruajfh0),, initially all were an ARRAY formula but I've re applied them ( F2 and ENTER) then copied below so did the same for others,, then SAVED and Open ,, now all are Non Array formula ,,, may be U have entered an ARRAY formula ,, since I found them !!

Comment: @RajeshS I really appreciate your input. But when I download the file via the link in my question, there are no array formulas in there. This is what makes it so frustrating, it's fine for me!
I think it may be a problem with my system (or how my organisation has set my system up) - as myself and my colleagues open the file to standard formulas, but my client always sees the array formulas, but I wouldn't know where to start looking if that is the issue.

Comment: Hi @Andy,, ask your client once apply the procedure what I did,, and save the file,,, BTW this never happens automatically,,, may be the file has some Macro behind,, or once better check the source file.

Answer (score 0):

Excel with the dynamic array feature (AFAIK Office 365 only) got the @ operator. It will limit a function or formula result to one value/one cell. If a formular isn't initiated with @, other Excel versions will see an array function in various circumstances, which is OK in most cases, but sometimes fails.

As far as I understand, the limitation to one result is only necessary as last step of the whole formula, so you would need the @ operator on the outer IF() function:

```
=@IF( ...
```

and only there.

Answer (score 0):

*Redoute*, Thank you for your answer. Yes this appears to be a "feature" of Office 365, it sometimes (?!?) automatically either converts a formula to an array or prefixes the formula with "@". I haven't got to the bottom of the when and/or why, however, prefixing a formula with "@" at least stops it appearing in earlier versions as an array.
The annoying thing is the auto-array feature only appears as an array in earlier versions (so looks like a straight formula in Excel 365), whereas an actual array appears as an array (ie "{=...}") in both new and old versions, so definitely appears to be a bug.